# Sharepoint List Online and Power Automate - Date Field Trigger?

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a SharePoint list, and I'm looking into how I can use power automate to trigger a workflow.

Each item has a last reviewed date, and then a primary owner and secondary owner.  If the last reviewed date is 30 before 1 year out, then I want to send an email to the primary owner.  This condition will need to be built out, because I then need to check if that initial reminder has been sent.  7 days after that initial reminder is sent, if the item has not been reviewed (review date updated and item versioned) then send a 2nd reminder, this time to the primary and secondary owner of the item.

Does this make sense? I'm not seeing any automate triggers that would be based on a list item date field. Is this possible? Thank you for any insight!